# Restore Database SQL script not working

Tags: sql-server

I have used below to restore .bak file which is in remote server and it is not working.

```
restore database Status_backup
from disk = N'E:\Status bak files\Status_backup_201404302300.bak'
with 
    move 'Status_backup_201404302300' to N'E:\Files\Status_backup_201404302300.mdf',
    move 'Status_backup_201404302300' to N'E:\Files\Status_backup_201404302300.ldf'
```

I am getting below error

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 25 Cannot open backup device
>   'E:\Status bak files\Status_backup_201404302300.bak'. Operating system
>   error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.). Msg 3013, Level
>   16, State 1, Line 25 RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Please suggest what is error in the script?

Comment: It is clearly said in error message: "The system cannot find the path specified.". Make sure backup file exists at location you've specified and accessible to account under which SQL server is running.

Comment: in folder 10 .bak files exists with datetime stamp. which account do I need to check?

Answer (score 0):

Your path contains spaces. Add double quotes or change the path name to something without spaces.

As it turns out in the comments, your actual problem is the location of the file being on another machine. You try to access a remote file with a local path. You should copy the backup file(s) to your local computer (where your sql server apparently is) and try again with the corresponding path.

Comment: did you just replace the single quotes with double quotes or did you enclose the path in double quotes and enclose the whole string in single quotes?

Comment: just replaced single with double quotes. is that wrong?

Comment: are the sql server and the file on the same computer? do you have sufficient permissions for restoring? are the path/file permissions sufficient for the sql server to access the file?

Comment: if this is the problem, you need both. i wrote "_add_ double quotes" ;)

Comment: no SQL server and file are not on the same computer. SQL server is in my local machine. .bak files are in remote server. would that be a problem? how to check whether do I have permission or not fro restoring? I do not have anyone to get to know whether I have permission or not. I have to check myself. so, please let me know where do I need to check?

Comment: sure, your remote server has no drive E: (or it means, say, its dvd drive). your paths are local paths, if you use them in sql queries and so the file has to be on the machine, where the server is running.

Comment: actually remote server has E drive but my local machine do not have E drive. which server you mean. usually I used to connect to remote server using rdp. sorry if I am not clear

Comment: or this way, sorry. see my edited answer, this should make it clear.

Comment: ok you understand my issue. Thanks. there is not enough space to copy all those files to my local computer. I tried with one small file. which is 12 gb copied to my F folder. then I tried using the same Restore command still getting same error. Please can you let me know whether do I need to change anything in restore command?

Comment: you have to change your path to the _corresponding_ location, e. g. F:\mydbs\backups\whatever.bak

Comment: I have used this          RESTORE DATABASE Status_backup_2015_05_31_230001_686899
 FROM DISK = 'F:\bckup\Status_backup_2015_05_31_230001_686899.bak'
WITH MOVE 'Status_backup_2015_05_31_230001_686899' TO 'F:\Files_bckup\Status_backup_2015_05_31_230001_686899.mdf',
MOVE 'Status_backup_2015_05_31_230001_686899' TO 'F:\Files_bckup\Status_backup_2015_05_31_230001_686899.ldf'

Comment: showing error Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 59
Cannot open backup device 'F:\bckup\Status_backup_2015_05_31_230001_686899.bak'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 59
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: are you sure that all path and file names are correct?

Comment: So your folder is really named "bckup" and not "backup"?

Comment: The error message still says the system is not able to find the path. Have you tried without the `move` statements? As I can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186858(v=sql.120).aspx#restoring_db_n_move_files) the movement sources contain suffixes "_Data" and "_Log", which resemble the logical file names of your database. Maybe you need to fix them as well.

Comment: tried this RESTORE DATABASE Status_backup_2015_05_31_230001_686899
FROM DISK = 'F:\bckup\Status_backup_2015_05_31_230001_686899.bak'
WITH MOVE 'Status_backup_2015_05_31_230001_686899_Data' TO 'F:\Files_bckup\Status_backup_2015_05_31_230001_686899.mdf',
MOVE 'Status_backup_2015_05_31_230001_686899_Log' TO 'F:\Files_bckup\Status_backup_2015_05_31_230001_686899.ldf'

Comment: This time getting this error   Msg 3234, Level 16, State 2, Line 59
Logical file 'Status_backup_2015_05_31_230001_686899_Data' is not part of database 'Status_backup_2015_05_31_230001_686899'. Use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to list the logical file names.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 59
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: now do, what the error message tell you. find out, how exactly the logical files are named.

Comment: Thanks. is there any command to check Logical file names of .bak files?

Comment: again, please see your error message. it even tells you the command and then google its syntax. if this ultimately leads again to the 3201 error and your pathes really are correct, we still must be talking about different things.

Comment: ok. sorry for bothering. I got the command. to see log files.

Comment: I'm not sure if we've established that these files are on the SQL Server i.e. when you RDP into the server you should be able to see the files _on the server that you've RDP'd into_. You definitely need to copy the files on to the SQL Server and use the path that makes sense as if you were on the SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
RESTORE DATABASE Status_backup 
FROM DISK = 'E:\Status bak files\Status_backup_201404302300.bak'
WITH
   MOVE 'Status_backup_201404302300' TO 'E:\Files\Status_backup_201404302300.mdf', 
   MOVE 'Status_backup_201404302300_log' TO 'E:\Files\Status_backup_201404302300.ldf', 
REPLACE
```